# Cycle detection in inheritance

Tags: java, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I am currently writing a java compiler, one of the things that i have to enforce is acyclic inheritance. I was wondering what is the best way to check this requirement is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this part](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.4) of the JLS, specifically the part at the bottom of 8.1.4 that says "a class C directly depends on a type T if...".

The JLS is your go-to reference if you're writing a Java compiler. You'll probably end up knowing the whole book like the back of your hand.

Comment: I know the hierarchical rules, what i asked for is a cycle-detection algorithm.

Comment: Isn't there a recursive algorithm for it laid out in the section I linked?

Comment: Ops thought it was in pseudo-code format. I just found it...Thanks!